# configuration not found in org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.25: 'compile'

Tags: java, ivy

I have used log4j 2 bridge to update Log4J version. In doing so, I have also updated slf4j-api version to 1.7.25 and slf4j-log4j12 version 1.7.25. I am using ivy when I try to run the build it gives me unresolved dependency error like below:
org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.25: configuration not found in org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.25: 'compile'. It was required from org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;1.7.25 compile
Below is how I have added dependency in ivy.xml

I have downloaded these jars from maven repository which also downloads ivy-1.7.25.xml for both the jars and this is how it looks for slf4j-log4j12:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
    <info organisation="org.slf4j"
        module="slf4j-log4j12"
        revision="1.7.25"
        status="release"
        publication="20170316220700"
    >
        <description homepage="http://www.slf4j.org">
        SLF4J LOG4J-12 Binding
        </description>
        <m:properties__project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</m:properties__project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <m:dependency.management__log4j__log4j__version>1.2.17</m:dependency.management__log4j__log4j__version>
        <m:properties__maven-site-plugin.version>3.3</m:properties__maven-site-plugin.version>
        <m:properties__project.build.resourceEncoding>UTF-8</m:properties__project.build.resourceEncoding>
        <m:properties__log4j.version>1.2.17</m:properties__log4j.version>
        <m:properties__project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</m:properties__project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <m:properties__junit.version>4.12</m:properties__junit.version>
        <m:properties__slf4j.api.minimum.compatible.version>1.6.0</m:properties__slf4j.api.minimum.compatible.version>
        <m:properties__required.jdk.version>1.5</m:properties__required.jdk.version>
        <m:properties__logback.version>1.0.13</m:properties__logback.version>
        <m:dependency.management__ch.qos.cal10n__cal10n-api__version>0.8.1</m:dependency.management__ch.qos.cal10n__cal10n-api__version>
        <m:properties__javadoc.plugin.version>2.10.4</m:properties__javadoc.plugin.version>
        <m:dependency.management__org.slf4j__slf4j-jdk14__version>1.7.25</m:dependency.management__org.slf4j__slf4j-jdk14__version>
        <m:properties__maven.compiler.target>${required.jdk.version}</m:properties__maven.compiler.target>
        <m:properties__cal10n.version>0.8.1</m:properties__cal10n.version>
        <m:dependency.management__org.slf4j__slf4j-api__version>1.7.25</m:dependency.management__org.slf4j__slf4j-api__version>
        <m:maven.plugins>org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-compiler-plugin__3.3|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-jar-plugin__2.3.1|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-surefire-plugin__2.19.1|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-source-plugin__2.1.2|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-assembly-plugin__2.2|org.codehaus.mojo__build-helper-maven-plugin__1.7|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-site-plugin__3.3|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-compiler-plugin__3.3|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-jar-plugin__2.3.1|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-surefire-plugin__2.19.1|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-source-plugin__2.1.2|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-assembly-plugin__2.2|org.codehaus.mojo__build-helper-maven-plugin__1.7|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-site-plugin__3.3</m:maven.plugins>
        <m:properties__maven.compiler.source>${required.jdk.version}</m:properties__maven.compiler.source>
    </info>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="default" visibility="public" description="runtime dependencies and master artifact can be used with this conf" extends="runtime,master"/>
        <conf name="master" visibility="public" description="contains only the artifact published by this module itself, with no transitive dependencies"/>
        <conf name="compile" visibility="public" description="this is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths."/>
        <conf name="provided" visibility="public" description="this is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide it. It is only available on the compilation classpath, and is not transitive."/>
        <conf name="runtime" visibility="public" description="this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath." extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="test" visibility="private" description="this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases." extends="runtime"/>
        <conf name="system" visibility="public" description="this scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository."/>
        <conf name="sources" visibility="public" description="this configuration contains the source artifact of this module, if any."/>
        <conf name="javadoc" visibility="public" description="this configuration contains the javadoc artifact of this module, if any."/>
        <conf name="optional" visibility="public" description="contains all optional dependencies"/>
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="slf4j-log4j12" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="master"/>
        <artifact name="slf4j-log4j12" type="source" ext="jar" conf="sources" m:classifier="sources"/>
        <artifact name="slf4j-log4j12" type="javadoc" ext="jar" conf="javadoc" m:classifier="javadoc"/>
    </publications>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.7.25" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>
        <dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.17" force="true" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*)"/>
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.7.25" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)">
            <artifact name="slf4j-api" type="test-jar" ext="jar" conf="" m:classifier="tests"/>
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.12" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <override org="log4j" module="log4j" matcher="exact" rev="1.2.17"/>
        <override org="ch.qos.cal10n" module="cal10n-api" matcher="exact" rev="0.8.1"/>
        <override org="org.slf4j" module="slf4j-jdk14" matcher="exact" rev="1.7.25"/>
        <override org="org.slf4j" module="slf4j-api" matcher="exact" rev="1.7.25"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

and this is how it looks for slf4j-api

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="org.slf4j" module="slf4j-api" revision="1.7.25" status="release" publication="20230425124605" default="true"/>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="default" visibility="public"/>
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="slf4j-api" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="default"/>
    </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

any pointers will be very helpful

Comment: IVY dependency that I have added:
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.7.25" force="true" conf="default-&gt;default;compile-&gt;default;app-&gt;default"/>
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.7.25" force="true" conf="compile-&gt;default;app-&gt;default;sources-&gt;sources"/>